# Destroying users is slow and throwing errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, user-accounts, account-destruction

During my semi-wheneverifeellikeit spammer destroying session this morning, I found that destroying users (simple ones, single-post / no activity) has gotten insanely slow. In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6952623/user6952623), it disassociated [their posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39971409/1849664) but didn't follow through on destroying the user (gave me a server error).

In other cases, it succeeds... after a significantly longer time than usual. This seems to have started this morning, I don't remember seeing this before.

Edit: Looks like the linked user above *did* get destroyed, eventually. Still, something isn't right here.

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't like this morning (UTC time).

Comment: Just reproduced. Disassociated the answer from the account, anonymised the user name, but didn't actually remove the account.

Comment: @ChrisF On which site?

Comment: @AdamLear - Stack Overflow. I posted the links in the blue room

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: Please don't test using my account kthx

Comment: @Won't - as if we would ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had some database trouble related to the [launch of the Developer Story](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/10/bye-bye-bullets-the-stack-overflow-developer-story-is-the-new-technical-resume/). It should all be resolved now, so go forth and destroy. :) Shout at me if there are still any lingering issues.